# Custom "reason-phrase" along with the status code for head/render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'm looking for a way to set a custom [reason Phrase](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) when responding with a

```
head 450
```

or a

```
render status: 450
```

Rails will respond with a `HTTP/1.1 450 Custom` but I'm implementing a Protocol where a `HTTP/1.1 450 Out of Sync` needs to be returned. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this via the `render` or `head` calls really. At least not according to the docs and skimming through the rails code briefly.

Maybe someone here knows a clever trick how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want to add new status codes + reasons for those custom codes, not trying to turn `200 OK` into `200 LOL`.

As a partial answer that someone else might be able to expand upon, you can create an initializer with the following:

```
require 'rack/utils'

custom_codes = {
  "Out Of Sync" => 450
}

custom_codes.each do |reason, code|
  # allow `status: :out_of_sync`
  Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[reason.tr(' ', '').underscore.to_sym] = code

  # tell it what reason to use for this status code
  Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[code] = reason
end
```

and now when you do:

```
head 450
head :out_of_sync
render status: 450
render status: :out_of_sync
```

the Rails log will show:

```
Completed 450 Out Of Sync in 17ms
```

However, when I use `curl` or the developer tools in Safari, they still show `450 CUSTOM`. I'm not sure if Rack is modifying this after Rails hands it off or if the tools are ignoring the text and just showing a default message or what is going on. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to dig further.

Answer (score -1):

Don't. If your protocol *relies* on the reason phrase, it's broken by design.

See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.3.1.2.p.3:

> The reason-phrase element exists for the sole purpose of providing a textual description associated with the numeric status code, mostly out of deference to earlier Internet application protocols that were more frequently used with interactive text clients. A client SHOULD ignore the reason-phrase content

It also has been removed in HTTP/2.

Comment: It's not *my* protocol, I'm consuming a service which relies on this. I'm aware that the client should ignore the phrase, but it doesn't and it's not in my power to change anything about it. I can either deal with it or not use their protocol, which is not an option. But thanks